# Calculating the density of an MNIST database grayscale image

Tags: python, image, numpy, pixel

Using this function:

```
import numpy as np

def blockshaped(arr, nrows, ncols):
    ''' Return an array of shape (n, nrows, ncols) where
        n * nrows * ncols = arr.size

        If arr is a 2D array, the returned array should look like n subblocks with
        each subblock preserving the "physical" layout of arr.
    '''
    h, w = arr.shape
    assert h % nrows == 0, "{} rows is not evenly divisble by {}".format(h, nrows)
    assert w % ncols == 0, "{} cols is not evenly divisble by {}".format(w, ncols)
    return (arr.reshape(h//nrows, nrows, -1, ncols)
               .swapaxes(1, 2)
               .reshape(-1, nrows, ncols))
```

I was able to divide my image into blocks of 16 pixels each.
What I want to do is calculate the density of the black pixels in each block.
I know that the values of pixels range from 0 to 255.
I wanted to do `black_density = numberof_zeros / 16`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to know the density of black, in each block of your image you simply do

```py
np.sum(block_shaped(img, 16, 16).reshape(-1, 16*16) <= black_threshold, axis=1)
```

If you are uncertain about the threshold you could try [Otsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) method, either by blocks or the whole image, it depends on what you really want.